# Java: KeyListeners does work, but only works when I type space

Tags: java

This only works when I type the space bar. When I tab space bar, it will print "you typed" and it doesn't get into the if statement when I tab up arrow.
How can I make it to print "k" when I tab up arrow?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Tester extends JPanel{

  JFrame frame;

  public Tester(){

    frame = new JFrame("Testing...");
    TestK k = new TestK();

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,700));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(k);

  }

  public class TestK implements KeyListener{

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

      int key = e.getKeyCode();
      System.out.println("You typed");
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        System.out.println("K");
      }

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv){

    Tester t = new Tester();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `keyReleased` instead of `keyTyped` and while you're at it, make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, this will avoid the need for a follow up question on why your `KeyListener` has stopped responding to anything at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyReleased` instead of `keyTyped`.

If you read the JavaDocs for `KeyListener`, you will be sent to the JavaDocs for [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), which states

> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the
>   platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode
>   character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about
>   character input. In the simplest case, a key typed event is produced
>   by a single key press (e.g., 'a'). Often, however, characters are
>   produced by series of key presses (e.g., 'shift' + 'a'), and the
>   mapping from key pressed events to key typed events may be many-to-one
>   or many-to-many. Key releases are not usually necessary to generate a
>   key typed event, but there are some cases where the key typed event is
>   not generated until a key is released (e.g., entering ASCII sequences
>   via the Alt-Numpad method in Windows). No key typed events are
>   generated for keys that don't generate Unicode characters (e.g.,
>   action keys, modifier keys, etc.).

The important part here is

> No key typed events are
>   generated for keys that don't generate Unicode characters (e.g.,
>   action keys, modifier keys, etc.).

which is why `keyTyped` is not been called.

While you're at it, you should be making use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, this will avoid the need for a follow up question on why your `KeyListener` has stopped responding to anything at all

Comment: Additionally, KeyListeners need direct keyboard focus. For example, if you were to add a slider into a JFrame and give it keyboard focus (i.e. clicking on it) the KeyListener would immediately stop responding. KeyListeners are *more suitable for individual key presses* and serve as a low level method of responding to them.